# Vmware / vmdk / virtual machine hosting providers?

Tags: vmware-server, cloud-hosting, vmware-vmdk

I'm new to cloud/virtual hosting and having a difficult time finding much useful information on google about this question.

Are there any reputable hosting providers out there, aside from hosting.com, who allow you to upload and manage your own vmware server virtual machines, rather than providing you with their standard images?

Is this a viable option for scaling a web application in transition between shared and dedicated hosting? Any major downside?

edit -- found this:

http://www.greentreehosting.com/hosting/vmware-virtual-machines/

http://vmware-hosting.com/

http://www.lunahost.com/Services/PrivateVirtualMachines/tabid/68/Default.aspx

After talking to some reps I'm getting the impression that these services are *highly* overpriced. Is this typically the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lowest tier out there for vmware hosting is [vCloud Express](http://www.vmware.com/solutions/cloud-computing/public-cloud/vcloud-express.html).

A big jump in features but not price would be [vCloud Datacenter](http://www.vmware.com/solutions/cloud-computing/public-cloud/vcloud-datacenter-services-providers.html).

Links go to list of providers.

Regarding "highly overpriced:" You get what you pay for. Higher price generally means higher SLA, redundancy, performance, features, etc.

Comment: +1 for "you get what you pay for"

Comment: These links have broken.  Searching for the terms does yield results, though.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.vmdkhosting.com offers uploading of VMDK/VMware images, or shipment of USB drive(s), and exclusively support VMware.

It appears they do not allow storage appliances though (Nexenta, FreeNAS).  So if you are just uploading a normal VM they are probably your best bet.